# Elegant way to create a dictionary of pairs, from a list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have defined a tuple thus:
    (slot, gameid, bitrate)

and created a list of them called `myListOfTuples`. In this list might be tuples containing the same `gameid`.

E.g. the list can look like:

```
[
   (1, "Solitaire", 1000 ),
   (2, "Diner Dash", 22322 ),
   (3, "Solitaire", 0 ),
   (4, "Super Mario Kart", 854564 ),
   ... and so on.
]
```

From this list, I need to create a dictionary of pairs - ( `gameId`, `bitrate`), where the `bitrate` for that `gameId` is the first one that I came across for that particular `gameId` in `myListOfTuples`.

E.g. From the above example - the dictionary of pairs would contain only *one* pair with `gameId` "Solitaire" : `("Solitaire", 1000 )` because 1000 is the first bitrate found.

NB. I can create a set of unique games with this:

```
uniqueGames = set( (e[1] for e in myListOfTuples ) )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For python2.6

```
dict(x[1:] for x in reversed(myListOfTuples))
```

If you have Python2.7 or 3.1, you can use katrielalex's answer

Answer (score 4):

```
{ gameId: bitrate for _, gameId, bitrate in reversed( myListOfTuples ) }.items( )
```

(This is a view, not a set. It has setlike operations, but if you need a set, cast it to one.)

Are you sure you want a set, not a dictionary of `gameId: bitrate`? The latter seems to me to be a more natural data structure for this problem.

Comment: Thanks katrielalex - I get a syntax error just after the `for`. Why the `reversed`?

Comment: The `reversed` is because repeated dictionary assignment to the same key overwrites its value; we want the *first* value in the list, so we iterate backwards. I assume you're using Python 2.x, since dictionary comprehensions are new to Py3k. You can do the same thing with a generator, though it's a bit messier. Fixing.

Comment: I see. Yes, a dictionary would be more useful actually.

Comment: dict comprehensions are in Python2.7 too

Comment: @BeeBand, if you just want a dict, leave off the `.items()`